# Search for closest date in dates array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a dates array in javascript
I want to search for a date and I dont expect it to be there
but I want to get the most closest date to it
so how can I do this ?

```
    function search_date(date) {
    var m = 1;
    var dateFound;
    var xdate = function (m) {
        mh.data.find(function (d) {
            if (Math.abs((new Date(d.x)).getTime() - date.getTime()) <= 30) {
                return d;
            } else {

                if ((new Date(d.x)).getMinutes() - date.getMinutes() <= m) {
                    if (Math.abs((new Date(d.x)).getSeconds() - date.getSeconds()) <= 30) 
                        return d;
                }


            }
        });
    };
    var found = false;
     while(!found){
        if (xdate(m) != undefined){
            dateFound = xdate(m);
            break;
        }else{
            m++;
    }
     }

    console.log(dateFound);
}
```

Comment: What have you tried?  What problems are you facing?  Can you post your code?

Comment: sorry for that , i have edited the post with my code

Comment: set up a selection between dates with set parameters and let it loop for each search result. Provide a container that you fill with dates that fall within these parameters and then at the end select manually after you've written result to file or printed to stdout. Add that type of test to your question and show the error... if that pops up... Currently you're asking us to code for you. Therefore my hint how to do it without giving you specific code.

Comment: thank you for that , actually I found sorting them and compare is the best solution in my situation , if a date is larger than the parameter date , it will be the nearest one to the previous of the larger date in the ascending sorted array ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to break this down into some reusable parts.  We need to be able to calculate the difference in two dates, and we need to be able to find the minimum value of an array based on some calculation (in this case the difference from our target date.)

Here's an approach which does that:

```js
const dates = [new Date("2018-02-18T20:24:33.000Z"), new Date("2018-02-18T20:45:02.000Z"), new Date("2018-02-18T21:22:50.000Z"), new Date("2018-02-18T22:06:31.000Z"), new Date("2018-02-18T22:47:18.000Z")]

const timeDiff = (first) => (second) => Math.abs(first - second)

const minBy = (fn, list) => list.reduce(
  ({d, val}, item) => fn(item) < d ? {val: item, d: fn(item)} : {d, val},
  {d: Infinity, val: null}
).val

const closestDate = (dates) => (testDate) => minBy(timeDiff(testDate), dates)

console.log(closestDate(dates)(new Date('2018-02-18T16:52:35')))
```